# why I just show once my user list in fragment, when I change the fragment and back, it will not show user list

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

why I just show once my user list in fragment, when I change the fragment and back, it will not show user list.

the function is working, but I don't know why just show once time.

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
private MessageListAdapter messageListAdapter;
private List<ChatListModel> usersList;
private List<UserModel> mUsers;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container,false);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    usersList = new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseReference reference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatlist").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                usersList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    ChatListModel chatListModel = snapshot.getValue(ChatListModel.class);
                    usersList.add(chatListModel);
                }
                chatList();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


        return view;
}
```

```
private void chatList() {
        mUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    UserModel userModel = snapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                    for(ChatListModel chatListModel : usersList){
                        if(userModel.getId().equals(chatListModel.getId())){
                            mUsers.add(userModel);
                        }
                    }
                }
                messageListAdapter = new MessageListAdapter(getContext(), mUsers);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(messageListAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I never got any crash, just change other fragment and back it. the fragment will show blank page.

Comment: did you use replace or add for fragment transaction

Comment: no, I just click BottomNavigationView to change fragment, so where did I modify?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine do u know how to solve it?

Comment: Can you create a logcat on `onCreateView`. check it if it trigger if you go to that fragment

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I have add logcat few mins ago, when I click first time it will trigger the chatList(); but when I change to homefragment ot other fragment then back to messagefragment, it will not trigger the chatlist(); so how do I do now?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine is it I used viewpager so cannot display?

Comment: Have you solve the problem ?